# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php when after sync with github desktop

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-routing, github-desktop

My laravel project is showing this error: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php` when i am trying to sync my project to github using github desktop, except for this route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

but another simple route like following will not work, and return that error.

```
Route::get('loa', function () {
    return view('loa');
});
```

In route list, using route command: `php artisan route:list` it says it exists. but it always returns Route not found. I also have tried to use the command `dump-auto load` or `route:clear`, but nothing is working.

Comment: remove / before loa

Comment: no, i knew that..still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run composer update then try again.